# Create Dynamic Wordpress Pages from Dynamic URLs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 230 dynamically generated URLs that are using data from a custom table in my Wordpress database.

Here is the code to create the URL:

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row["slug"]."</td><td><a href=\"/mypage/".$row["slug"]."\">".$row["name"]."</a>"."</td></tr>";
```

The URLs (with the code above) come in looking like this:

```
mysite.com/mypage/new-page-1/
mysite.com/mypage/new-page-2/
mysite.com/mypage/new-page-3/
```

Each URL appears to point to a specific custom page, but those pages don't exist yet.

How can I dynamically generate an actual page for each one of these URLs so I don't have to create each page manually and so I can edit these pages from within the Wordpress admin dashboard?

Any help is always appreciated!

Comment: We can do that. But it's pretty hard if each post is different post type.

Comment: They would all have the same post type - page.